# Syntax for SAGA resampling

Tags: python, raster, qgis-plugins, saga, resampling

How can I link the GUI to my processing code as shown in the image below so that it uses any number selected (between 20 and 100) in the spinSize value space?

[image: gui]

```
# Perform task
if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer and self.dlg.checkPixel.isChecked():

index = self.dlg.spinSize.currentIndex()
num_cell = self.dlg.spinSize.value()

processing.run('saga:resampling', {"INPUT" : output1, "KEEP_TYPE" : True, "SCALE_UP" : 0, "SCALE_DOWN" : 0, "TARGET_USER_SIZE" : num_cell, "TARGET_USER_FITS" : 1, "OUTPUT" : output2})
```

Comment: I need help, please.